# Multiuser IRC server using threads

Tags: c, multithreading, server, irc

I'm writing an IRC Server using 'C' language.

I used threads for multiple connections and compiled without errors but I couldn't connect multiple users.

Am I using threads in a right way ? in the right step ?

When User-1 connects I create a thread for him. But when User-2 tries to connect, will the code flow start from the first line ? Should I create a loop so that User-2 could pass create and listen socket functions ?

My code:

```
#include "init.h"
#include "struct_user_channel.h"
#include "manip_chaines.h"
#include "pthread.h"

#define PORT 6667  //Port number
#define BACKLOG 10

void *connection_plusieurs(void *client_fd);

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
  /*Connection parameters variables */
  struct sockaddr_in server;
  struct sockaddr_in dest;
  int socket_fd, client_fd;
  socklen_t size;
  pthread_t thread_id;

  int yes = 1;
  /*Socket creation*/
  if ((socket_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
  {
    /*in case of failure*/
    fprintf(stderr, "Socket failure!!\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  if (setsockopt(socket_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int)) == -1)
  {
    perror("setsockopt");
    exit(1);
  }

  memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server));
  memset(&dest, 0, sizeof(dest));

  /* define connexion parameters : port,host,ect ... */

  server.sin_family = AF_INET;
  server.sin_port = htons(PORT);
  server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

  /*bind socket c'est à dire associcer la socket à notre adresse local*/

  if ((bind(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(struct sockaddr)))
      == -1)
  { //sizeof(struct sockaddr)
    fprintf(stderr, "Binding Failure\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  /* Listen :*/

  if ((listen(socket_fd, BACKLOG)) == -1)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Listening Failure\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  /* If we have listener*/
  size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
  /*Accept connexion*/

  while ((client_fd = accept(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &dest,
      (socklen_t*) &size)))
  {
    if (client_fd == -1)
    {
      perror("not accept");
      exit(1);
    }
    /* Send acceptation message */

    printf("Server got connection from client %s\n", inet_ntoa(dest.sin_addr));

    /***************************************************************************
     *                                     *
     * Once connexion done we will use threads to maintain multiple connexions *
     *                                     *
     *                                     *
     ***************************************************************************/

    while (1)
    {
      if (pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, connection_plusieurs,
          (void*) &client_fd) < 0)
      {
        perror("could not create thread");
        return 1;
      }
    }
  }

  return 0;
}

void *connection_plusieurs(void *client_filedesc)
{
  char buffer[10241];
  char buff[3000];
  int num = 0;
  int client_fd = *(int*) client_filedesc;
  num = recv(client_fd, buffer, 10240, 0);
  if (num == -1)
  {
    perror("recv");
    exit(1);
  }
  else if (num == 0)
  {
    printf("Connection closed\n");
    return 0;
  }
  else
  {
    recv(client_fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 50000);

    strcpy(buff, "001");
    /* on envoi 001 pour le client pour ---> mode +i l'utulisateur est reconnue que par les utilisateurs de meme channel avec /who or whois*/
    send(client_fd, (char *) buff, sizeof(buff), 0);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: '(void*) &client_fd' why do devs. keep doing this?  'client_fd' can be reloaded by a second accept() return before the first client<>server thread can read it into its local var:(

Comment: You might like to (again?) go over the concept on how `accept()`ing connections work to TCP.

Comment: For your reference: http://unpbook.com

Comment: Your actual question I could not understand:(

Comment: 'send(client_fd, (char *) buff, sizeof(buff), 0);' will send "001", its NULL-terminator and 2996 bytes of garbage:(

Comment: I assume that 'connection_handler' in 'if (pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, connection_handler,' is a translation artifact and is really 'connection_plusieurs' in your real code?

Comment: for the first comment. sould I put accept returns in a table so that i'm sure to not inference between users fd?

then for the moment is ok if send returns garbage (2996)

My global question is how to connect multiple users, because I think that my program is not far to work but for the moment I don't get what I want..

Comment: yes is the same I change it before posting but not in main sorry

Comment: Ohwait... your accept() call is outside the while(1) loop.   Move it inside!!  Funny - I get this deja-vu feeling..

Comment: nice now it accepts 2 connection but when I put command it tells me not connected to server..

Answer (score 0):

The errors are here:

```
    while (1)
    {
      if (pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, connection_plusieurs,
          (void*) &client_fd) < 0)
      {
        perror("could not create thread");
        return 1;
      }
    }
```

With the `while (1)` you are creating numerous threads where you should create just one single thread. And you don't notice that eventually the creation fails due to memory exhaustion, because the return code of [`pthread_create()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_create.html) is checked the wrong way, since it won't be less than 0:

> If successful, the *pthread_create()* function returns zero.
>   Otherwise, an error number is returned to indicate the error.

Correct:

```
    if (pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, connection_plusieurs, &client_fd) != 0)
    {
      perror("could not create thread");
      return 1;
    }
```